# Updating the texture image node using python

Tags: python, texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

Updating texture image node issue using python.

I have several different texture input files that I want to render out using the same node group setup and blender file.

Python doesn't seem to be updating the texture image node as expected

I'm using @Chris script located at https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218744/86978

I've narrowed down the issue to the line **bpy.data.images[fileName].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name**

when it tries to execute this line it creates an error
`KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "2plantpic_test.png" not found'` or
if I use the **full path** it gives this error
`KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "/tmp/tex_tures/2plantpic_test.png" not found'`

Things I've tried / checked:

1. The files are located in the directory **/tmp/tex_tures/**
2. If I rem out the line `bpy.data.images[fileName].filepath = eachFile` the files and directories get created but the different image texture files I want to be rendered out aren't rendered (since it doesn't change the texture image node).
3. Replaced the **bpy.data.images** line with `eachFile = bpy.data.images.load(eachFile)` but the image textures still aren't being updated to the new PNG images

How the script is suppose to work:

1. Loop through all **PNG** files in the **/tmp/tex_tures**
2. Replace the image texture file node with each PNG file found and render them out.
3. Place the render files into their own separate directory

The Script is below:

```
import bpy
import glob
import os


print ("Script start")

scn = bpy.context.scene

here = bpy.path.abspath('/tmp/tex_tures') #textures location

output_path = scn.render.filepath

for eachFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(here, '*.png')):
    print("-------------------")
    print("eachFile: ",eachFile)
    fileName = bpy.path.basename(eachFile)
    print("fileName: ",fileName)
    fileNameStart = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
    print("fileNameStart: ", fileNameStart)
    
    eachFile = bpy.data.images.load(eachFile)
    #bpy.data.images[fileName].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name
    #bpy.data.images[eachFile].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name
    #print("texture name used: ",bpy.data.images[fileName].name)
    #bpy.data.images['/tmp/tex_tures/2plantpic_test.png'].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name
    
    directory = os.path.join(here, fileNameStart)
    print("directory", directory)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(directory,"")

    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
    
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

**I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 Linux Blender 2.93.3**
I've also attached the blender file and image of nodes

[image: img1]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Use the name of the image used in your texture node.  IMO prob should `texture_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)` To load and assign new image to texture instead of loading new image into old. Would instead look at using  an image sequence as mentioned in other answers or in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217733/is-possible-play-video-in-reverse-mode-into-texture-image-node

Comment: Thanks I've replace the `bpy.data.images` line with `eachFile = bpy.data.images.load(eachFile)` but the image textures still aren't being updated to the new PNG images.

Comment: In the line: bpy.data.images[fileName] the fileName has to be a string of an already loaded image datablock in the blend file. Chris uses an existing image datablock and replaces the source filepath of the image in his loop, not the complete datablock. To create a more "correct" and clean solution, you should probably use what @batFINGER mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: _ie_ look at your texture node in the blend (which I haven't DL'd) and use the name of the image it currently uses.  To use load `bpy.data.materials["The name of your material"].node_tree.nodes["The name of your texture node"].image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)`  or if in a node group `bpy.data.node_groups["The name of your node group"].node_tree....`

Comment: @batFINGER I uploaded a image copy of the node tree.  I was just trying to replace the texture images in the texture node with the PNG image files.  I'm not using any materials are you saying that's required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) to *load* and *assign* the image to the texture node in one go as already explained in [How to load an image from disc and assign it to a newly created image texture node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201412/how-to-load-an-image-from-disc-and-assign-it-to-a-newly-created-image-texture-no/201414#201414). How you can get a reference to any shader node is nicely explained in [Control Cycles/Eevee material nodes and material properties using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-eevee-material-nodes-and-material-properties-using-python/23446#23446).

Demo on how to iterate through a *list of images* (by using the default hdris), assign each to the default cube, set the render path based on the originals and call the render operator:

[image]

```
import bpy
import os

C = bpy.context
scn = C.scene

# Get the images
folder = bpy.path.abspath("//images")
images = [os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith(".exr")] 

# Get the material
mat = C.object.active_material
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

# Get the node
img_node = nodes.get("__PLACEHOLDER__")
if img_node:
    # Iterate through all images, replace the image
    for img in images:
        img_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(img)
        # Set the output path and render (jpg is a placeholder)
        img_folder, img_file = os.path.split(img)
        img_name, img_ext = os.path.splitext(img_file)
        scn.render.filepath = bpy.path.abspath("//rndr_{}.jpg".format(img_name))

        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

As [mentioned by @batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235441/updating-the-texture-image-node-using-python#comment399223_235441) in the comments, more god-like would be converting the list of images into a real sequence (`img_000.exr`, `img_001.exr`, `img_002.exr` etc.) and control the playback using the *Offset* property of the image node. Explanation: [Is possible play video in reverse mode into Texture Image node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218235/31447)

Comment: Thanks that helped