# I can't run the script because I can't find the "Placeholder" node

Tags: rendering, scripting

I am using Blender 3.0.1.

I need to render about 1000 textures on one object. It takes too long to do it by hand, so I decided to use a script and google. Some time later, I found what seems to be the perfect solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235459/141788

But, either I have the wrong version of Blender or some other error, but I don't have the "Placeholder" node.

As you can see, it is used here: `img_node = nodes.get("__PLACEHOLDER__")`

Here are the nodes that are currently in the workplace:[image]

Comment: I think placeholder is meant to be replaced by you for your specific need

Comment: Replace it with "Image Texture" or whatever the name **not the label** of your image texture is

Comment: Thx guys, im so stupid, xd.